How to vertically align text and image with the bottom elements in CSS?
I am working on a layout where I have some text on the left side and an image on the right side. Below them, I have three smaller images. I want to align the left text and the right image so that they both vertically align with the bottom images.
Here is my current layout:
As you can see in the image:
• The text on the left is higher than the bottom images. 
• The large image on the right is also higher than the bottom images.
What I want to achieve:
• I want the text on the left to be vertically aligned with the bottom images. 
• I also want the large image on the right to be vertically aligned with the bottom images. 
• The gap between the text and the image should be exactly 160px.
I’ve tried adjusting the margins and padding, but I haven’t been able to get the alignment correct. What would be the best approach in CSS to achieve this alignment?
I’ve created a Fiddle to demonstrate the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/fptL74bx/
I think the necessary adjustments need to be made in the following section of the CSS code in fiddle.
.intro {
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 160px;
  justify-content: center;



"so that they both vertically align with the bottom images." - do you mean "horizontally align"? That is, the left hand side of the text to be aligned with the left hand side of the first image and the right hand side of the image to be aligned with the right hand side of the third small image?

@A Haworth. Yes, correct.

Please put a runnable snippet into your question, not on an external site which may disappear rendering your question useless for furure readers.

Do you really want all those fixed px values? The whole set up looks like a fairly simple grid which would adjust to whatever space is available horizontally.

@A Haworth I am copying the design which I have received. Everything should match pixel to pixel.

How horribly non-responsive!

Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself  preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link.

i add this line to css in your jsfillde
 .description{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
 .main {
   background-color: green;
   padding: 0 55px;
 }  
.section {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    gap: 40px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding-bottom: 160px;
}

and also removed p height.

Did you try it in the fiddle? It doesn't work for me. I was wondering if you could send the updated fiddle. Just to let you know, I can't change anything in the bottom images, they are perfectly set. The only place I want to make changes is in the text and image above.

yes i tried and it worked

Can you share the updated fiddle ?
